# Why can't I use a 'str[0]' to decode an enum in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, char

I'm parsing a string coming from a 'black box' screen controller and thought I'd be able to use enum to interpret the various parameters. I'm trying to understand why my approach won't work and although I know its something to do with types and casts I can't seem to reach a conclusion. I'd like to know if its just fundamentally a wrong approach or I'm missing something more basic. The stream arrives as a string array terminated with \n and I split it but then need to analyse the first letter of each 'token' dealing with the value according to what 'letter' is in 'str[0]'.

obviously didn't get the point across, I'm not looking for a coded solution just an understanding of where my wrong assumptions are.

```
    enum TL_parEnum : char {X = 0, Y = 1, Z = 2};
    
    struct TL_params {
          bool seen;
          float value;
        };
        TL_params TL_parbuffer[9]{false,0};
    
    while (TL_parsub = strtok_r(TL_param, " ", &TL_param)) {
              char p = TL_parsub[0];
          switch (TL_parsub[0]) { 
          case 'Y' :
             TL_parbuffer[p].seen=true;
             TL_parbuffer[(TL_parEnum)p].value =atoi(&TL_parsub[1]);
    }
```

the above fails because (TL_parEnum)p doesn't evaluate through the enum I either get the char 'Y' or the ascii 59. BUT if I hardcode (TL_parnum)Y it works as expected.

I've tried casting to and from char, *char, even my own constructions like TL_parEnum(j) but I only get the ascii code or the letter not something that I can use to 'decode' the enum.

So am I making poor assumptions about how this should work?

Also this is for an embedded controller so I don't have access to all the C++ goodies and I'm wondering if that is a factor.

Comment: `(TL_parEnum)char j[0];  // fails and returns ascii code for Y` .. ? From above, `char j = Y;` as well making this question a bit.. 'unclear'.

Comment: `char j[0];` isn't valid C++

Comment: you duplicate the variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum`s are largely a compile-time feature; the fact that it's named `Y` isn't relevant once the code is compiled (aside from in debugging symbols). You can't convert from a character *describing* the name of an `enum` member to the member itself without manually coding a lookup table for it in some way. Even if `j[0]` contains `'Y'`, the program has no idea that that maps to the member `Y` with value `1` when it's time to execute the code.

If you want to enable this sort of conversion, I'd recommend writing a simple function with a `switch` statement for `char` that has cases for each ASCII character covered, and returns the appropriate `enum` member (with a default that raises an exception or terminates the program when an unrecognized character is provided).

Comment: Thank you ShadowRanger - and every one else who offered a comment. Knowing enums are compile time clarifies things. I was trying to avoid the very long switch table I'm about to write and just got lost in a maze of twisty passages.